# Create one date time java class and access it on all Jframes

Tags: java, swing

I want to create one date and time class for show date and time on all frames (My Swing Application).  It means though number of frames are create i want display date and time using created java class.so what is the best way to do it?

I tried this code to do it.

Testing Code......

```
final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Date date = new Date();
        String time = df.format(date);
    }
});

timer.start ();
```

I want to access this time variable or whatever Methodist to show time on all Frames using this timer.

Comment: You want to have a single instance of date right?did you try anything?

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: Have you considered putting that class on your `CLASS_PATH` and then importing it where you want to use it?

Comment: By *"..or whatever Methodist"* DYM *"..or whatever method it is"*?  ..Because the other is simply nonsense (even though 'Methodist' is a valid word).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry.i want to display time on all frames my swing application using created one java class and access it.so how can do it better way?

Comment: Your question remain woefully lacking in necessary detail. Please put as much effort into asking your question as you'd like someone to expend answering it.

Comment: *"Sorry"*  An [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19440938/edit) to make it more clear, is better than apologies.

Comment: how to show time 5 jframes when one time class is written ?

Comment: `"how to show time 5 jframes when one time class is written ?"` -- please clarify as this doesn't make sense to me. Write out what you mean by this. And while you're at it, clarify your entire question please.

Comment: suppose..i create jframe and i want to show time.then i create simedateformat object and show it.
(simpledateformat object * 5 (jframes) = 5 sdf objects)
but if i create one time class for it can i access it for 5 jframes ?

Answer (score 3):

> i want to create one date and time class for show date and time on all frames(My Swing Application).

What do you mean by "date and time class"? Java already has a Date variable. Do you mean a common object of this type? Also your having multiple JFrames concerns me as an application usually only has one JFrame, and this suggests a design problem that may or may not have bearing on your problem.

> it means though number of frames are create i want display date and time using created java class.so what is the best way to do it ?

If you want a single object, then pass it into your other objects when they are created, perhaps with a constructor parameter. But again, you really really do not want to create a lot of JFrames. The user will thank you if you don't.

Comment: *"..you really really do not want to create a lot of JFrames. The user will thank you if you don't."*  See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for my views (AKA rave) on the topic.